# Javascript object with inside array issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am not experienced with javascript and sometimes it pulls out weird issues like this that I can't figure out even if I find on google solutions for what I want to do.

Doing this console logs:

```
console.log(this.data.proSkills);
console.log(this.data['proSkills']);
```

This is the result:

```
{id: "xhg6jdfKRdjl1OHGIqwT", proSkills: Array(2)}
{id: "xhg6jdfKRdjl1OHGIqwT", proSkills: Array(2)}
```

Intellisense is giving me extentions methods/properties like forEach and length but they are all undefined.

```
console.log(this.data['proSkills'].length);

this.data.proSkills.forEach(f => {
  console.log(f);
})
```

Result:

```
undefined
[sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.data.proSkills.forEach is not a function
```

This is how the full object looks like:

```
{id: "xhg6jdfKRdjl1OHGIqwT", proSkills: Array(2)}
      id: "xhg6jdfKRdjl1OHGIqwT"
      proSkills: Array(2)
         0:
            name: "ffffff"
            __proto__: Object
        ...
```

I am trying to update an array to firebase, if length is greater than 0 then populate the reactive form with the array and update if length is 0 then just add values, this is all I want to do but I can't access the inside array since length is undefined and I can't even get to print the array in the console because it shows the whole object anyways.

Comment: Where does that object come from, and what is the relationship between that context and the point in your code where you attempt to `console.log()` the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `console.log(this.data.proSkills)` is logging an *object*:

```
{id: "xhg6jdfKRdjl1OHGIqwT", proSkills: Array(2)}
```

That object has a property `proSkills` that *is* an array. So it should be

```
this.data.proSkills.proSkills.forEach(someCallbackFn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data has an id and the array proSkills, add  another .proSkills like this:

```
this.data.proSkills.proSkills.forEach(...)
```